# Matrix of Controller to View - ZF

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, matrix

In the **controller**

My Matrix is `$mes`:

```
print_r($mes);


Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
          [0] => 0 
          [1] => 0 
          [2] => 0 
          [3] => 0 
          [4] => 0
          [5] => 0 
          [6] => 3 
          [7] => 1 
          [8] => 0 
          [9] => 0 
          [10] => 0 
          [11] => 0 
          [12] => 0 
      ) 
   ) 
 Array ( 
      [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 0 
            [1] => 0 
            [2] => 0 
            [3] => 0 
            [4] => 0 
            [5] => 0 
            [6] => 2 
            [7] => 0 
            [8] => 0 
            [9] => 0 
            [10] => 0 
            [11] => 0 
            [12] => 0 
         ) 
     )
```

Send data to view:

> $this->view->repMes = $mes;

In the view

```
<?php print_r($this->repMes); ?>

Array ( 
  [0] => 0 
  [1] => 0
  [2] => 0 
  [3] => 0 
  [4] => 0 
  [5] => 0 
  [6] => 2
  [7] => 0 
  [8] => 0 
  [9] => 0 
  [10] => 0 
  [11] => 0 
  [12] => 0 
)
```

As can be evidenced missing the first part of the matrix, as it could be solved?

Comment: There may be a bug in old zend 1 library that proccess an action twice(in some browsers and still i don't know why!!), so you will see two array output after print_r.Update your zend library to latest zend 1.x.x

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to have a two dimensional array but looking at you code i see you have two different arrays . so you $mes variable points to the second array that is why  you see only the second array in the view. you should have you array in the controller as:

```
 $mes =   Array ( 
               [0] => Array ( 
                      [0] => 0 
                      [1] => 0 
                      [2] => 0 
                      [3] => 0 
                      [4] => 0
                      [5] => 0 
                      [6] => 3 
                      [7] => 1 
                      [8] => 0 
                      [9] => 0 
                      [10] => 0 
                      [11] => 0 
                      [12] => 0 
                  )
              [1] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 0 
                        [1] => 0 
                        [2] => 0 
                        [3] => 0 
                        [4] => 0 
                        [5] => 0 
                        [6] => 2 
                        [7] => 0 
                        [8] => 0 
                        [9] => 0 
                        [10] => 0 
                        [11] => 0 
                        [12] => 0 
                     )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice when you print your matrix, it shows as two different arrays, that is because your code flow is not sending the right array.

1. Your array "$mes" should be this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 0, 
        [1] => 0, 
        [2] => 0, 
        [3] => 0, 
        [4] => 0,
        [5] => 0, 
        [6] => 3, 
        [7] => 1, 
        [8] => 0, 
        [9] => 0, 
        [10] => 0, 
        [11] => 0, 
        [12] => 0 ),
   [1] => Array ( // See here you should have the second subindex, and not the closing and reopening
        [0] => 0, // of "Array"
        [1] => 0, 
        [2] => 0, 
        [3] => 0, 
        [4] => 0, 
        [5] => 0, 
        [6] => 2, 
        [7] => 0, 
        [8] => 0, 
        [9] => 0, 
        [10] => 0, 
        [11] => 0, 
        [12] => 0) 
 )
```

I would suggest using a pro-tempore counter variable to check if your "print" is repeating

Some like:

```
echo "<pre> Loop --> \n";
print_r($mes);
echo "End Loop\n</pre>";
```

This way you can check the real array.